# split-brain recovery with crm-fence-peer script

Tags: pacemaker, drbd

I implemented DRBD resource level fencing with `crm-fence-peer.9.sh` and `crm-unfence-peer.9.sh` scripts on both nodes.

[image]

Now, I have the following situation on my lab nodes:

- both nodes `otrs1` and `otrs2` are online
- resource are running on `otrs1`
- as per `drbdadm status` `otrs1` holds the primary role and `otrs2` holds the secondary role

[image]

Now when I reboot `otrs1` on `otrs2` I get the following message:

[image]

Can see that the resources are moved to `otrs2`:

[image]

I can see the location constraint create:
[image]

If the replication link becomes connected again and DRBD completes its synchronization process, then the constraint is removed. The cluster manager is now free to promote the resource. In fact the constraint is now removed:

[image]

But as soon I disable the NIC on `otrs2` (the currently active node) I can see the split-brain occurred:

[image]

Obviously this is a split-brain scenario. Why's that so ? is it because

> In case of the crm-fence-peer script it is necessary that Pacemakers
>   communication stays available when DRBD’s network link breaks.

Source [https://docs.linbit.com/docs/users-guide-9.0/#s-automatic-split-brain-recovery-configuration](http://LINBIT%20documentation)

Answer (score 1):

Correct. It is most likely because of:

> In case of the crm-fence-peer script it is necessary that Pacemakers
>   communication stays available when DRBD’s network link breaks.

I am assuming you only have the one NIC/network link. So, when you take down the NIC the pacemaker cluster splits. As the cluster nodes can no longer communicate at all, the current primary node cannot place the constraint in the peer's CIB as it cannot communicate with the peer.

To avoid split-brains in this situation you will either need true node level fencing (STONITH), or at the very least, multiple communication paths for Corosync.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just want to put into consideration that in production both nodes would run as guests virtualized with VMWare. Is there any node level fencing agent for that ? Could you possibly point my to any documentation ?

Comment: PS. yes you are correct there's only one NIC in each node but what I don't get is why does that same not happen when the node gets rebooted ? I mean the connection is interrupted as well, when the other node reboots it can't have its CIB update either, right ?

Comment: How is the node rebooted? Is it a graceful reboot, or an abrupt power-cycle of the node? The behavior would be very different depending.

I don't use vmware myself, but I know others have used the fence_vmware_soap STONITH agent with success.

Comment: I was using the `reset` functionality within VirtualBox.

Comment: PS. why would it make a difference? Could you please explain ? Thank you!